# Omit closing tag in HTML in Visual Studio 2013 when using ReSharper 9

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, tags

I am one of those guys who believes that closing tag on a HTML5 void element is hideous.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and coding in Razor templates (cshtml). 
So when I insert a HTML void element (`<input>`, `<br>`, `<meta>` etc.) then Visual Studio autocomplete the insertion with a closing tag (`<input/>` and not `<input>`).

I have tried to turn this feature off by go into

Tools → Options → Text Editor → HTML → Advanced

And then set 'Auto insert closing tag' and 'XHTML coding style' to 'False'.
I have also installed ReSharper and it also have an option for insert closing tag in Razor template.

Unfortunately it seems that none of what I have done works. 
The editor still autocomplete all void elements with a closing tag.

Is it me or is Visual Studio so rooted in the XHTML mindset that I cannot get rid of it?

---

EDIT:

It is ReSharper 9 who does the auto completion and not Visual Studio. It seem that you cannot turn the /> off for void elements. At least I could not find it in the option tree. My hack is just to turn off the IntelliSense for HTML. Then I still gets the auto-completion for the Razor and C# syntax.

[image: ReSharper 9 - Options - IntelliSense - General]

Comment: That's weird. Setting "XHTML coding style" to False does work for me. Try restarting? Reloading your config? Not sure.

Comment: Okay. It is not Visual Studio there is the problem. After I have disabled Resharper it works. So the problem is in ReSharper. Not Visual Studio. So one point to VS and zero to me. I have tried to reboot the machine in order to reset the ReSharper deamon but it does not help. The configuration must be somewhere in ReSharper.